# How to create a javascript in HTML that generates/returns an image from an existing image?

Tags: javascript, html, image, draw

I am developing a webpage that uses a google map. I customized the icon/marker of the google map if it points to a certain specific location. The icon/marker was customized successfully and pointed to an image returned from facebook:

sample image passed as icon/marker: https://graph.facebook.com/astig.bertz/picture

I wanted to have a border of the image. In other words I wanted to create another image out of the image from facebook profile pictures.

Can someone help me? thanks.....

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a Canvas. If not for the end-display then at least for the image manipulation.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial

They even have an example that puts a fancy border around an image:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images#Art_gallery_example

Comment: ive tried but it results to this: http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=252877778066025&set=a.104127182941086.8381.100000314130481&type=1&pid=869801&id=100000314130481

i wanted to create this sample image: http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=252876574732812&set=a.104127182941086.8381.100000314130481&type=1&pid=869799&id=100000314130481

Comment: i did not use canvass because google map marker doesn't accepts html tags. and that is the reason why i want to generate another image from an image itself.  :(

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible without using server resources. JavaScript itself doesnt have the ability to manipulate binary data at that granularity.

However, you could attempt to use some javascript / css trickery to make that image the background url of a div you have placed a border on. AKA something like:

```
<div style="-webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; background: url(/path/to/some/image); border: 1px solid black;">
</div>
```

Comment: creates this marker: http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=252877778066025&set=a.104127182941086.8381.100000314130481&type=1&pid=869801&id=100000314130481

i wanted to do this look like this: http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=252876574732812&set=a.104127182941086.8381.100000314130481&type=1&pid=869799&id=100000314130481